# Having trouble populating the FilteringSelect (dojo)

Tags: javascript, dojo, dijit.form

I have the following json

```
{
Name: 
Phone:
Contact:
list:
{
Gender:
[
Male
Female
]
}
}
```

I am trying to display Gender info in the filtering select. If a user clicks on the filtering select arrow it should display Male, Female(Gender info).

```
store1 = new dojo.store.Memory({data: a1});  //a1 has list values in it
var f1 = new dijit.form.FilteringSelect({
                    name: "list",
                    placeHolder: "Select gender",
                    store:dojo.data.ObjectStore({ objectStore: store1}) 
                }, "f1");
```

Please can anyone help me..

Regards.

Answer (score 1):

I think the store has to implement the identity API, which dojo.store.Memory doesn't ( yea the docs show it as the example but it doesn't seem to work).

Try this for store1:

```
var tdata = {
            identifier:'idd'
            ,label:'name'
            ,items:[
                {idd:'a',name:'Rawr'}
                ,{idd:'b',name:'lok'}
            ]
        };
        var store1 = new dojo.data.ItemFileReadStore({ data: tdata });
```

Comment: Please use "Code sample" button to format your code sample. Also you should correct indentation.